# Angular - How to show ng-reapet value inside button value

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple question, how to show the `ng-reapet` value:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in list">
{{i.msg}} // the value
 <input type="button" value="i.msg"/> // not working
</tbody>
```

Inside a `button` value:

```
<input type="button" value="i.msg"/> // not working
```

Thanks.

Comment: show us your list data in controller

Comment: It is from http request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="button" value="{{i.msg}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-value="i.msg"** and put **td tag** after **tbody tag** for this.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in list">
    <td>
      {{i.msg}}
      <input type="button" ng-value="i.msg" />
    </td>
</tbody>
```

Created Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/nh7Q0ym2yXSWgxMlcHJS?p=preview